# sharedDeadLetterStrategy is not discarding the DLQ messages

Tags: activemq-classic, messagebroker

Am using AMQ 5.5. I would like to disable the option of sending dead letters to ActiveMQ.DLQ destination and completely discard (automatically) the messages that would be sent there otherwise. To do this I had configured the broker as below:

```
<amq:destinationPolicy>
        <amq:policyMap>
          <amq:policyEntries>
            <amq:policyEntry topic=">" producerFlowControl="false" >
                <amq:deadLetterStrategy>
                      <amq:sharedDeadLetterStrategy processExpired="false" />
                </amq:deadLetterStrategy>
            </amq:policyEntry>
            <amq:policyEntry queue=">" producerFlowControl="false">
                <amq:deadLetterStrategy>
                      <amq:sharedDeadLetterStrategy processExpired="false" />
                </amq:deadLetterStrategy>
            </amq:policyEntry>

          </amq:policyEntries>
        </amq:policyMap>
    </amq:destinationPolicy>
```

However, I still see that the messages are getting stored in DLQ. Can you please let me know what could be causing this?
Do I need to fix anything in the config?

Thanks

Hari

Comment: Can somebody please help me out with this? Its causing our data dir to grow un-necessarily.

Answer (score 2):

The problem faced here was that, the above given configuration would discard only non-persistent expired messages. To discard all expired messages, persistent and non-persistent, use discardingDLQBrokerPlugin.

`<amq:plugins>`

`<amq:discardingDLQBrokerPlugin dropAll="true"/>`

`</amq:plugins>`